# Creating a CGPath from a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, sprite-kit

I’m using SpriteKit for my game, and would like a type of per-pixel physics. In iOS 7, (I think) the only way to do this is with the `bodyWithPolygonFromPath:` method. My images are a bit complicated though, so, instead I’d like to create a more basic shape of my image then create a path from that alpha image.

Is is possible to turn my image in to a CGPath to use for the physics body?

I know in iOS 8 there are APIs to do this, but I want my game to run on iOS 7 too.

Comment: PhysicsEditor (ext. tool) can do that

Comment: Could you link me to the specific docs/api in Cocos2D please?

Comment: it's a tool, you'll find it with google

Comment: Apologies, mistook your name for a link at a glance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PhysicsEditor(PE) like someone mentioned or you can use [SKPhysicsBody Path Generator](http://dazchong.com/spritekit/). All you need to do is drag and drop your sprite, and it will generate the objective-c code for you.

---

**EDIT:**

I have used PE before for cocos2d games, but I have no idea how to use PE with SpriteKit (since PE doesn't natively support SpriteKit just yet).

Comment: Link seems dead. And this doesn't help to do it at runtime.